# Windows Phone app throws exception (quit automatically) when running under 3G, but fine with WIFI. Very weird

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient, html-agility-pack

I have tried hundreds of times to find errors for this piece of codes.
It only works through WIFI, but When I switch off WIFI on my phone, and run the app again, this app just shut down automatically, which means it thrown an exception.

The app is simple, I used WebClint() to download HTML source and parsed it with HTML Agility Pack, then added them to a list, foreach the list to creat each news object.

I have tried catch the exception stacktrace and bind it to a texblock, It said some of ArgumentOutOfRange exception and Genericlist(int32 index)???

I have no idea about it, It was fine in wifi, but not in 3G network. Can anyone help?

```
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string srcHTML;
    HtmlNode UrlNode;
    ObservableCollection<News> newsList = new ObservableCollection<News>();
    List<HtmlNode> headlines;
    HtmlDocument hd;
    News n;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClenet = new WebClient();
        webClenet.Encoding = new HtmlAgilityPack.Gb2312Encoding();
        webClenet.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.6park.com/news/multi1.shtml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        webClenet.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClenet_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }


    private void webClenet_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        srcHTML = e.Result;
        GetHeadlinePage(srcHTML);
    }
    private void GetHeadlinePage(string srcHTML)
    {
        hd = new HtmlDocument();
        hd.LoadHtml(srcHTML);
        try
        {

            UrlNode = hd.DocumentNode.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[8].ChildNodes["tr"].ChildNodes["td"].ChildNodes["ul"];
            headlines = UrlNode.Descendants("a").ToList();

            foreach (var headline in headlines)
            {

                if (headline.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("6park"))
                {
                    n = new News();
                    n.NewsTitle = headline.InnerText;
                    n.NewsUrl = headline.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    n.NewsDetails = headline.NextSibling.InnerText.Replace("- ", "新闻来源：") + headline.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText + headline.NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling.InnerText;
                    newsList.Add(n);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //NewsSource.Text = ex.StackTrace + "\n" + ex.Message;
        }




        NewslistBox.ItemsSource = newsList;
        //NewsHeadlineWebBrowser.NavigateToString(ConvertExtendedASCII(headNews));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd debug the value passed to `GetHeadlinePage()`.

I'd suspect that the response is different based on the network or the request is timing out or you're getting some other error.

I'd assume that the call to `LoadHtml()` is failing as this isn't inside any exception handling/trapping and you've not validating the value passed to it.